# How to store output of command line in variable in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using this method to pass in a command as a string. But I don't want to just output it to console.log. When someone calls commandLine('aplay -L') for example, the output that would be displayed on command line should be returned as a variable or a JSON response. The callback itself is where the stdout is, but how do I return it to a variable?

```js
commandLine = function(command, callback) {
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;
  exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {

    if (err && err.length > 1) {
            console.log("failed to find playback or record devices");
            callback(error("InternalError", "No input or output devices found", 500));
            return;
        }else{
        callback(stdout); //returns cmd line output 
    }  
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way

Your commandLine program: Check for `calllback(null,stdout)` and `callback(error,stderr)` . Also see the return. We are returning the child_process. **This is important as the exec is async, we should get the output only after the stdio streams are closed**

```
commandLine = function(command, callback) {
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;
  var child_process = exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {

    if (err && err.length > 1) {
            console.log("failed to find playback or record devices");
            callback(error("InternalError", "No input or output devices found", 500));
            return;
        }else{
            if(stdout){
                    callback(null,stdout); //returns cmd line output 
            }
            if(stderr){
                callback(new Error("STDERR"),stderr);
            }

    }  
  });
  return child_process;
};
```

The invoker where stdout gets called (since ping is a valid command):

```
var cmd_output = '';

var cp = commandLine('ping',function(err,data){
    console.log("Callback called");
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    cmd_output = Buffer.from(data).toString('utf8');
})

cp.on('close',function(){
    //cmd_output is already populated above. If you want just console.log here or leave it
    console.log(cmd_output);
})
```

Comment: This still results in the output being sent to console.log(data). What I need is the function call commandLine('ping',function(err,data){...} to return the output as a string or have a local variable hold the value of data. Having it in console.log isn't what I need at all. thanks

Comment: When you get some data you can assign it to any local variable. The important thing is how you send the data using callback. I'll updated with the complete example.